# How to make a gust of smoke collide with 3d text

Tags: physics, collision

I've got a gust of wind blowing smoke on some 3d text, however, there's no EFFECTOR or collision in the physics tab to choose from for text, now what? LOL

I can make the smoke collide with Suzanne - or objects, just not with text.

Comment: what about creating an invisible effector that has the shape of your text, or just convert your text to mesh?

Comment: Wow! Who would think it was that easy?! Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

As moonboots said, just convert the text to mesh

[image]

then use it as effector:

[image]

Comment: That's a great illustration what I'm trying to do, thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you and You are welcome!